# Debug function that "disappears" in some cases

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11

Suppose I have a debug function that is defined like this:

```
namespace debug {
    void report(std::string message);
}
```

Can I pull some compiler trick that will, when compiled, replace every call safely with a `nop`. I dont want to call an empty function, I want to not call the function at all.

If it is possible... can I make a namespace "disappear", too?

Debug executables will be compiled with the symbol `DEBUGEXECUTABLE` defined (I can imagine some tricks with macros).

Comment: Note that calling an empty function should cause the compiler to go "Hey, why am I calling an empty function?", and optimise the call out. Hence why most of the answers are showing using macros to call an empty function in non-debug builds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
namespace debug
{
    void report(std::string message); // ToDo - define this somewhere
}

namespace release
{
    template <class Y>    
    void report(Y&&){} // Intentionally do nothing
}

#if defined(DEBUGEXECUTABLE)
    namespace foo = debug;  // set foo to the debug namespace
#else
    namespace foo = release; // set foo to the release namespace
#endif
```

Then use `foo::report` in your code. I like this since it minimises the use of preprocessor macros and keeps any compiler errors broadly similar across the debug and release configurations.

Passing a *r-value reference* in the release mode will allow the compiler to optimise out any anonymous temporaries. For the debug family of functions, you ought to pass strings by constant reference though to avoid any possiblity of a value copy being taken: `void report(const std::string& message);`

Comment: This still does a `std::string` copy.  Try `template<class T> void report(T&&){}`?  Technically this causes its argument to be ODR-used, but not sure how to avoid that.  As an example, `report("hello")` causes an allocation in both debug and release.

Comment: Insufficient -- `report("hello")` shouldn't allocate in release.

Comment: I like the namespace idea and I guess I will go with the inline trick from @Mateusz Drost (+references). I'll objdump the result by tomorrow and tell you if gcc-4.8 optimizes it.

Comment: ++1, problems fixed!  Use gotbot to see the resulting assembly, which is clean.  I found `namespace {}` wrappers around the functions themselves made the unused one go away when compiling the `.o` file, which is useful.  (basically, modern version of `static`)

Answer (score 3):

This is as optimal as I can make it.

We define `DEBUG` to have a `report` that does something, and leave it out it to do nothing:  (or we can use whatever symbol you are using in your build process to distinguish debug and opt from production code)

```
#define DEBUG
```

We create two namespaces.  One is called `debug`, the other `release`.  In each we create an anonymous namespace, which makes it easy for the compiler to detect and discard unused functions:

```
namespace debug {
  namespace {
    void report(std::string const& s) {
      std::cerr << s << "\n"; // sample implementation
    }
  }
}
namespace release {
  namespace {
    template<class T>
    void report(T&&) {} // Or `class...Ts` and `Ts&&...` to handle more than 1 argument optionally.
  }
}
```

Here we create a namespace alias that differs in release and debug:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
namespace report=debug;
#else
namespace report=release;
#endif
```

And our main:

```
int main() {
  report::report("hello");
}
```

We can see the results of this under gcc 4.9 with `DEBUG` [defined](http://goo.gl/WJJHFT) and [not](http://goo.gl/hBWt5y) over at [godbot](http://gcc.godbolt.org/).  As you can hopefully see, when `#define DEBUG` is not defined, the compiler produces nothing but an empty `main`.

If it is defined, it compiles to what you'd expect.

Comment: I want to upvote it just because that I learn something new. (`namespace ... = ...;`)

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace debug {
#ifdef DEBUGEXECUTABLE
    void report(std::string message);
#else
    inline void report(std::string message)
    {
        //nop - compiler should optimize it
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: `report("hello")` causes allocations in your release build.  Compiler is unlikely to optimize it out.

Comment: 1) Most compilers WILL optimize it out unless You set O0
2) If You set 00 You don't care about nonoptimise allocations ;)
3) But if You care, then just use const std::string & and const char *
4) I just use declaration from question

Comment: --1: [no, you are not correct](http://goo.gl/uSzFsn) -- removing an allocation is not a trivial act, and does not follow under the as-if rule.

Comment: I linked to an online compiler that shows the output assembly.  You can pass `-lto` and watch as it does not eliminate the allocation and deallocation of the `std::string`.  Now maybe it magically happens at a later spot than the godbot compiler shows, but eliminating an allocation/deallocation under the 'as-if' rule is a pretty tricky bit of footwork.